# How to test Branch.io in simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios9, deep-linking, branch.io

I'm scratching my head how I'm supposed to test my branch.io integration on simulator.

For link generation, I'm using the Javascript/web SDK instead of the iOS SDK. When you click a button to 'view content in app' on my landing page, it will generate the link and follow it.

All this works just great, but when I open the jump page in the simulator, it never actually attempts to open the local app on the phone which has the same bundle identifier.

I would guess this might be because the current app store URL box is blank (because it doesn't exist yet)... but I am not sure how I'm supposed to test if it works if I can't get the deeplink to trigger it locally.

Thanks!

Comment: Any luck with this yet? Not able to get it to work either...

Comment: It only works on a device not in simulator, and also you have to click it from a messeges/email link, not from mobile browser/url bar. On top of that, the branch docs are wrong recommending deeplinks, you should probably try just try the HTTP API to generate a link and then add it as the href="" (if you're doing a web view like I did)

Comment: Yeah, finally got it to work :) had to open it from 'Notes'. It actually 'sort of' works in the simulator. If you click the link, then open the app, it will have the latest branch params in the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tallboy, unfortunately a simulator is not fit for testing deep links for two reasons:

1. there is no App Store on the simulator, so you cannot see true redirect behavior
2. the simulator does not support Universal Links

You're absolutely right -- you can click the link then manually open the app. In this case, we use our "deferred deep linking" mechanisms to determine that link was previously clicked. That method is discussed in our documentation [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/matching-accuracy/guide/#browser-to-app-fingerprint-match).

If you have questions about any of this, please ask. You can also reach the Branch team via support@branch.io.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly ideal, but if you're just trying to pass in static params to your app through a Branch link and test your app's implementation of them in the simulator, you can just hardcode them in the Branch `initSessionWithLaunchOptions:andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:` block. This block is called every time the application becomes active again (i.e., if it's backgrounded) and on application start, even if it's used in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

The Branch handler block passes in a `params` dictionary, which you can either override (they'll be nil or just contain a few keys, if the block wasn't called from a tapped link) or just create your own to pass into your app.

This obviously doesn't work for testing desktop web site redirects or App Store downloads (or for many other use cases for Branch), but if you just wanted to test redirecting into specific views for your app from a clicked link (or in my case, how a dynamically generated view would look on a 4S when I didn't have a 4S available to test on), it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by using the Reminders app, create a new list, add that url as new item in that list, then click/tap that link in that item. It should open  your app. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this problem. Just use any online note taking app from Safari. I've used googlekeep to create a new and pasted Branch url, then click/tap that link from there.